# Can a variable be used as a property?

Tags: c#, var

I'm looking to do something like this:

```
string currPanel = "Panel";
currPanel += ".Visible"
```

Now at this point I have a string variable with the name of a property that only accepts Boolean values. Can I some how do something like this:

```
<data type> currPanel = true;
```

so the actual property `Panel1.Visible` accepts it without any errors?

Comment: It's not entirely clear why you would want to do this but you should look into reflection. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No, you can't. `currPanel` is a variable of type string and has nothing to do with `Panel.Visible`. If you really want to access properties of classes via a string representation of their name, you should use reflection. Google for things like `GetType`, `GetProperty`, `GetProperties` ... etc

Comment: Explain in what context you need this. You can find control by names, and through proper casting just access the `Visible` property. You _can_ do this using reflection, but in general that's a really bad idea to solve most problems.

Comment: It *is* an interesting question, and there *are* languages which do not distinguish between data and code, so I think the downvotes are unjustified.

Comment: Question is justified and is clear, upvoted it.

Comment: What I'm tryin to do is something similar to macro substitution performed in a dBase language. I realize I'm storing the property name in  a string but that's because the property name itself is a string.When I set the variable currPanel, I want Panel1.Visible to accept it. Please remember I'm doing this in C#.

Answer (score 2):

Supporting both properties and fields, but only instance ones:

```
public static void SetValue(object obj, string name, object value)
{
    string[] parts = name.Split('.');

    if (parts.Length == 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("name");
    }

    PropertyInfo property = null;
    FieldInfo field = null;
    object current = obj;

    for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
    {
        if (current == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
        }

        string part = parts[i];

        Type type = current.GetType();

        property = type.GetProperty(part, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        if (property != null)
        {
            field = null;

            if (i + 1 != parts.Length)
            {
                current = property.GetValue(current);
            }

            continue;
        }

        field = type.GetField(part, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        if (field != null)
        {
            property = null;

            if (i + 1 != parts.Length)
            {
                current = field.GetValue(current);
            }

            continue;
        }

        throw new ArgumentException("name");
    }

    if (current == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
    }

    if (property != null)
    {
        property.SetValue(current, value);
    } 
    else if (field != null)
    {
        field.SetValue(current, value);
    }
}
```

example of use:

```
public class Panel
{
    public bool Visible { get; set; }
}

public class MyTest
{
    public Panel Panel1 = new Panel();

    public void Do()
    {
        string currPanel = "Panel1";
        currPanel += ".Visible";

        SetValue(this, currPanel, true);
    }
}
```

and

```
var mytest = new MyTest();
mytest.Do();
```

Note that I'm not supporting indexers (like `Panel1[5].Something`). Supporting `int` indexers would be feasible (but another 30 lines of code). Supporting not-`int` indexers (like `["Hello"]`) or multi-key indexers (like `[1, 2]`) would be quite hard.

Comment: The `SetValue()` code you show is trivial and not quite unique. Are you sure it _helps_ the OP, and if so, did you try searching for a duplicate? _"How to access or set properties using strings in "object.property.subproperty" format"_ has been answered plenty of times before.

Comment: @CodeCaster No and No... But I had hoped that after a long discussion "is it a good question/is it a bad question" someone else had already done the search. And on the usefulness... Someone had given positive comments... But yes, now that I think about it, I'm quite sure someone else has already asked the same question.

Answer (score -1):

From what I can see here is that you are using WPF. Things like this you accomplish with converters

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/285358/All-purpose-Boolean-to-Visibility-Converter

With MVVM and WPF you never need to do this